# JavaScript functions working by themselves but not working together

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions

Today I started building a dummy client-side web app project in order to improve my basic JavaScript skills. Basically, it's a scientific calculator imitation that runs on line. As you'll see in the code, there are buttons in my HTML file each of which calls to one of the JavaScript functions in my JavaScript file. The calculator doesn't work, I mean, at all, and as I tried debugging, every function in my JavaScript file works by them-self as intended, but seemingly they don't work together.

Here's my code:

```js
var currentMode = 'deg';
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
var lastChar = screen.value.slice(-1);

/**
* Auxiliary functions
*/

function isNumeric(val) {
 return !isNaN(parseFloat(val)) && isFinite(val);
}

function sine(val) {
 if (currentMode === 'deg') {
  return Math.sin(Math.PI * val / 180);
 }
 return Math.sin(val);
}

function cos(val) {
 if (currentMode === 'deg') {
  return Math.cos(Math.PI * val / 180);
 }
 return Math.cos(val);
}

function tan(val) {
 if (currentMode === 'deg') {
  return Math.tan(Math.PI * val / 180);
 }
 return Math.tan(val);
}

function ln(val) {
 return Math.log(val);
}

/**
* Calculator functions
*/

function addSpecial(val) {
 var nums = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
 var operations = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^'];
 
 if (screen.value === '0') {
  if (nums.indexOf(val) >= 0)
   screen.value = val;
  else if (val === '.' || operations.indexOf(val) >= 0)
   screen.value += val;
  else
   screen.value = '0';
 } else if (lastChar === '.' || operations.indexOf(lastChar) >= 0) {
  if (val !== '.' && val !== '=' && operations.indexOf(val) < 0)
   screen.value += val;
 } else {
  if (val !== '=')
   screen.value += val;
  else {
   if (lastChar === '.' || operations.indexOf(lastChar) >= 0)
    screen.value = 'SYNTAX ERROR!';
   else if (screen.value.split('(') !== screen.value.split(')'))
    screen.value = 'ERROR! Open or close parantheses!';
   else {
    try {
     screen.value = eval(screen.value);
    } catch(err) {
     screen.value = err.message;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

function setAngleMode(newMode) {
 if (newMode === 'rad') {
  if (currentMode === 'deg') {
   currentMode = 'rad';
   screen.value *= Math.PI / 180;
  }
 } else {
  if (currentMode === 'rad') {
   currentMode = 'deg';
   screen.value *= 180 / Math.PI;
  }
 }
}

function addSymbol(val) {
 switch (val) {
  case 'pi':
   screen.value = Math.PI;
   break;
  case 'e':
   screen.value = Math.E;
   break;
  case 'phi':
   screen.value = 1.61803398875;
   break;
  case 'gamma':
   screen.value = 0.5772156649;
 }
}

function clearScreen() {
 screen.value = '';
}

function clearLast() {
 screen.value.slice(0, -1);
}

function inverseVal() {
 var len = screen.value.length;
 var subs;
 for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
  for (var j = len; j > i; --j) {
   subs = screen.value.slice(i, j);
   if (isNumeric(subs)) {
    screen.value = 1 / parseFloat(subs);
    break;
   }
  }
 }
}

function addSquare() {
 if (isNumeric(lastChar) || lastChar === ')') {
  screen.value += '^2';
 }
}

function addPower() {
 if (isNumeric(lastChar) || lastChar === ')') {
  screen.value += '^';
 }
}

function addSquareroot() {
 if (isNumeric(lastChar) || lastChar === ')') {
  screen.value += '^(1/2)';
 }
}

function addRoot() {
 if (isNumeric(lastChar) || lastChar === ')') {
  screen.value += '^(1/';
 }
}

function addExp() {
 if (isNumeric(lastChar) || lastChar === ')') {
  screen.value += 'Math.E^';
 }
}

function addSin() {
 if (isNumeric(lastChar) || lastChar === ')') {
  screen.value += 'sine(';
 }
}

function addCos() {
 if (isNumeric(lastChar) || lastChar === ')') {
  screen.value += 'cos(';
 }
}

function addTan() {
 if (isNumeric(lastChar) || lastChar === ')') {
  screen.value += 'tan(';
 }
}

function addLn() {
 if (isNumeric(lastChar) || lastChar === ')') {
  screen.value += 'ln(';
 }
}
```

```css
h5 {
    text-align: right;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 3px;
}

input[type=text] {
    text-align: right;
    height: 50px;
    width: 176px;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 10px groove #888888;
    background-color: #E5DFA0;
    font-family: Luicida, monospace;
}

.scientific {
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    left: 33px;
}

.scientific input[type=button] {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background-color: #444444;
    color: #BBBBBB;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 2.5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 2.5px;
    border: none;
}

.scientific input[type=button].cardinal {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 2.5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 2.5px;
    border: none;
}

.scientific input[type=image] {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #444444;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 2.5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 2.5px;
    border: none;
}

.simple input[type=button] {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #222222;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.simple input[type=button].roman {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#calc-contain {
    width: 180px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>::Scientific Calculator::</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine.js"></script>
    </head><body>
        <div id="calc-contain">
            <img src="EnData.png" alt="EnData" width="180px" />
            <h5>SCIENTIFIC CALCULATOR</h5>
            <form id="calculator">
                <input type="text" id="screen" value="0" readonly />
                
                <div class="scientific">
                    <div class="line">
                        <input type="button" value="RAD" onclick="setAngleMode('rad')" />
                        <input type="button" value="DEG" onclick="setAngleMode('deg')" />
                        <input type="button" class="cardinal" value="C" onclick="clearScreen()" />
                        <input type="button" class="cardinal" value="CE" onclick="clearLast()" />
                    </div><div class="line">
                        <input type="button" value="sin" onclick="addSin()" />
                        <input type="button" value="cos" onclick="addCos()" />
                        <input type="button" value="tan" onclick="addTan()" />
                        <input type="button" value="ln" onclick="addLn()" />
                    </div><div class="line">
                        <input type="image" src="sqr.png" alt="square" onclick="addSquare()" />
                        <input type="image" src="nthp.png" alt="nth power" onclick="addPower()" />
                        <input type="image" src="sqrt.png" alt="square root" onclick="addSquareroot()" />
                        <input type="image" src="nthr.png" alt="nth root" onclick="addRoot()" />
                    </div><div class="line">
                        <input type="button" value="1/x" onclick="inverseVal()" />
                        <input type="button" value="(" onclick="addSpecial('(')" />
                        <input type="button" value=")" onclick="addSpecial(')')" />
                        <input type="button" value="exp" onclick="addExp()" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="simple">
                    <div class="line">
                        <input type="button" class="roman" value="&#960;" onclick="addSymbol('pi')" />
                        <input type="button" value="7" onclick="addSpecial('7')" />
                        <input type="button" value="8" onclick="addSpecial('8')" />
                        <input type="button" value="9" onclick="addSpecial('9')" />
                        <input type="button" value=":" onclick="addSpecial('/')" />
                    </div><div class="line">
                        <input type="button" class="roman" value="e" onclick="addSymbol('e')" />
                        <input type="button" value="4" onclick="addSpecial('4')" />
                        <input type="button" value="5" onclick="addSpecial('5')" />
                        <input type="button" value="6" onclick="addSpecial('6')" />
                        <input type="button" value="x" onclick="addSpecial('*')" />
                    </div><div class="line">
                        <input type="button" class="roman" value="&#966;" onclick="addSymbol('phi')" />
                        <input type="button" value="1" onclick="addSpecial('1')" />
                        <input type="button" value="2" onclick="addSpecial('2')" />
                        <input type="button" value="3" onclick="addSpecial('3')" />
                        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="addSpecial('-')" />
                    </div><div class="line">
                        <input type="button" class="roman" value="&#947;" onclick="addSymbol('gamma')" />
                        <input type="button" value="0" onclick="addSpecial('0')" />
                        <input type="button" value="." onclick="addSpecial('.')" />
                        <input type="button" value="=" onclick="addSpecial('=')" />
                        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addSpecial('+')" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get some functionality, (with some parenthesis errors). If it's not working AT ALL, I suspect you are loading the javascript before the DOM is ready which will cause errors with you `getElementById`. Try either loading in a `window.onload` handler or put the script before the closing body tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sir. Is everything otherwise all right with my javascript code or the way it's called from html?

Comment: I don't think everything is working. When I type `3+3=` I get "ERROR! Open or close parantheses!" But typing `3 1/x` gives the right answer.